# Separating a name out from one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's what I'm working with;

```
FirstName - Lastname
John Smith
```

Here's what I'm trying to do;

```
FirstName - LastName
John        Smith
```

I'm getting syntax errors and I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring it out;

```
update [TrainingDB].dbo.Person set
    FirstName, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName) as firstname
    , substring(FirstName, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName)+1, len(FirstName)-(CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName)-1)) as LastName
```

Heres the error I'm getting;

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Do I need to wrap that second line beginning with `set` ?

Really appreciate any help/advice.

Comment: The syntax must be `UPDATE [table] SET [column1] = {expression1}, [column2] = {expression2};`. And set `LastName` firstly.

Comment: Hi @Akina, Thanks for the response. Apologies for the improper tag.

When you say ```LastName``` firstly, am I correct in thinking you mean immediately following ```set``` ? Thanks again!

Comment: The [Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first port of call (before SO).

Comment: You're also updating every row in the table - normally you would target a specific row using a `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for SQL Server (MS SQL):

```
UPDATE Person
SET Lastname = SUBSTRING(FirstName, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName) + 1, LEN(FirstName)),
    FirstName = SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName) - 1);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a3c437b1a5c9d283c0fc8c2efc584d9b)

PS. The query will fail if the value does not contain a space char - you may add
`WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName) > 0` for troubleshotting.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
UPDATE Person
    SET FirstName = LEFT(FirstName, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName) - 1),
        LastName = STUFF(FirstName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName), '')
    WHERE FirstName LIKE '% %';
```

This works by:

- `LEFT()` takes everything up to but not including the first space in the name.
- `STUFF()` removes everything up to and including the first space in the name.
- The `WHERE` only does the update if there is a space in the name.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2016 onwards, you can use JSON functions to split the name into an array and get the values. One more approach of using JSON.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(firstName varchar(50), LastName VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @table(firstName)
values('John Smith')

UPDATE ta
SET firstName = json_value(t.NameArray,'$[0]') ,
    lastName =  json_value(t.NameArray,'$[1]') 
from @table as ta
CROSS APPLY ( 
select CONCAT('["',REPLACE(ta.firstName,' ','","'),'"]')
) as t(NameArray)

SELECT * FROM @table
```

```
+-----------+----------+
| firstName | LastName |
+-----------+----------+
| John      | Smith    |
+-----------+----------+
```